# Wsdl had no content type webservice Exception

Tags: web-services, soap, guidewire

A  Message.wsdl and corresponding datatypes.xsd are deployed in  webresources folder (location from which images like logo.png is displayed) of a server so that it can be accessed like http://localhost:8080/cc/resources/test/Message.wsdl
    Then created a WSC file for consuming a perticular service of this wsdl. When i am trying to consume this service getting an exception which is given below.

```
gw.xml.ws.WebServiceException: SOAP response envelope from http://localhost:8080/cc/resources/test/Message.wsdl had no content type
```

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge this can occur due to 2 reasons,

1. Your wsdl file does not contain a binding or necessary info wont be there in that binding
2. When using multiple bindings.

Share ur class code and wsdl file here. Will check that and update u.